# Blank screen when running cocos-2d empty example

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

First here are the versions I am running

- Cocos2d-x-3.11
- Android sdk (5.1.1 or 3.1.1 have same effect)
- Ant 1.9.7
- Eclipse
- Java 1.8
- NDK r10c
- Python 2.7.5

I was trying to get the sample projcet located in cocos2d-x-3.11/tests/cpp-empty-test to work.  I believe when running (by looking at the code) it should pop up with the generic "Hello-world" program, however on my device it shows simply a blank screen.

Steps that I did to get the project running

1. Open eclipse
2. Import directory in `C:\AndroidProgramming\Cocos\cocos2d-x-3.11\cocos\platform\android\java`
3. Import proj.android from `C:\AndroidProgramming\Cocos\cocos2d-x-3.11\tests\cpp-empty-test`
4. Project->Build all
5. click cppTest->Debug->as android application

Then the project loads onto my device.  No console errors or anything, however the screen is just black.

Then eclipse shows me a wierd thing, and idk, it could be a breakpoint but its a new ide to me.  I see no console indication or anything.  And the app does not crash.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Its throwing an exception. When this happens you're doing something wrong. In this case it's trying to load a shared library or DLL and can't either because it doesn't exist or some other error occurred. Also please don't post images of code, it's not searchable.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Right is a rather large class, and I think it might be a part of the cocos2d library.  What part of it would you like to see? It would be nice to know what it was trying to load.